# asp.net mvc migrations generates empty migrations files

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, migration

After adding new Migration I am getting file generated by vs 2012 but the file is empty , despite I have a changes in "Table" class.

```
     public override void Up()
    {
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
```

Anyone faced with this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

This generally indicates the Entity Framework did not detect any changes in your model. For this to happen you have to ensure two things:

1. Some class in your \models folder changes, (add a field, a data
   annotation, etc)
2. You must add a DbSet to you config. Do a file
   search on DbSet and make sure you add a line like this:

```html
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<YourProject.Models.YourClass> YourDbSetName { get; set; }
```